# Class member calls function template with callback function

Tags: c++, class, templates

I'm having trouble passing a callback function from within a class, when calling a template function. Here's a sample code:

sortedlist.h

```
#ifndef _sortedlist_h
#define _sortedlist_h

#include <vector>    

template <typename ElemType>
class SortedList {
public:
    SortedList(int (*compare)(ElemType a, ElemType b));
    ~SortedList();

    void push(ElemType newElem);
    ElemType pop();

private:
    std::vector<ElemType> v;
    int (*cmp) (ElemType first, ElemType second);
    void Sort();
};


template <typename ElemType>
SortedList<ElemType>::SortedList(int (*compare)(ElemType a, ElemType b)) {
    cmp = compare;
}

template <typename ElemType>
SortedList<ElemType>::~SortedList() {
}

template <typename ElemType>
void SortedList<ElemType>::push(ElemType newElem) {
    v.push_back(newElem);
    Sort();
}

template <typename ElemType>
ElemType SortedList<ElemType>::pop() {
    ElemType next = v.back();
    v.pop_back();
    return next;
}

template <typename ElemType>
void SortedList<ElemType>::Sort() {
    for (int i=v.size()-1; i>0; i--) {
        if(cmp(v[i], v[i-1]) < 0) {  //compare function
            ElemType temp = v[i];
            v[i] = v[i-1];
            v[i-1] = temp;
        }
        else return;
    }
}

#endif
```

game.h

```
#ifndef _game_h
#define _game_h

#include <string>
#include "sortedlist.h"

class Game {
public:
    Game() {};
    ~Game() {};
    void addPlayer(std::string name, int score);
    std::string getWinner();

    struct Player {
        std::string name;
        int score;
    };

    //compare function
    int highScore(Player one, Player two);

private:    
    SortedList<Player> list(highScore);

};

#endif
```

game.cpp

```
#include "game.h"

void Game::addPlayer(std::string name, int score) {
    Player newEntry;
    newEntry.name = name;
    newEntry.score = score;
    list.push(newEntry);    
}

std::string Game::getWinner() {
    return list.pop().name;
}

//compare function
int Game::highScore(Player one, Player two) {
    if (one.score == two.score) return 0;
    if (one.score > two.score) return 1;
    return -1;
}
```

sample main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "game.h"
using namespace std;

int main () {
    Game pacman;
    pacman.addPlayer("Beavis", 100);
    pacman.addPlayer("Butthead", 200);
    cout << pacman.getWinner() << endl; 
}
```

When I compile it on XCode, I get "'highscore' is not a type" error. I also tried moving Player and highScore outside of the class with similar results. What should I do instead?

Answer (score 4):

In C++ you cannot initialize class-members in-place. You need to do that in the constructor initializer list

```
class Game {
public:
    Game():list(highScore) {};
    ~Game() {};

    //compare function
    static int highScore(Player one, Player two);

private:    
    SortedList<Player> list;
};
```

The function needs to be declared as `static` in the class definition as `SortedList` calls it without a `*this` pointer, like an ordinary function.

Performance is really unnecessary bad of the comparison function because you always copy the two items to be compared when passing them as arguments. Better make the comparison function's type to receive const-references and change `highScore`'s signature appropriately

```
int (*compare)(ElemType const& a, ElemType const& b);
```

Comment: OK, I made the all the changes but still getting the following error on the constructor:

Invalid conversion from 'int(*)(Game::Player, Game::Player)' to 'int(*)(const Game::Player&, const Game::Player&)'

Comment: @Luciano: That would suggest that you forgot to make the change somewhere (the `highScore` function doesn't take references?). In C++, it would probably be more common to use `std::sort` or `std::stable_sort`, and use predicates that determine "less-than" relationship (`bool compare_scores(const Player& a, const Player& b) { return a.score < b.score;}`) - in some cases it might even make sense to overload `operator<`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I forgot to change highScore to const& as well.
I could use std::sort, but the whole point of the assignment is to create callback function. Thanks!

Comment: What if list is not a member, rather is initialized inside a member function. Example:
   static int TopScore() {
      SortedList<Player> topten() ...
I can't use the constructor, because topten is not a member.